# can not access the tftp server via web

Tags: ubuntu, tftp

my tftp server can be accessed via 
commandline

tftp  192.168.0.29
- get file
that is working

when I try to update the netgear, asking for a tftp server, it is not accepting my ip adresse.

How to configure the tfstp server for web access?

Thanks Thomas

Comment: Did you open the firewall on the computer that runs the TFTP server ? You will have to open port 69 (UDP) for the TFTP service to be accessible for other computers on your network.

Comment: yes it is open, it is all only in intranet, I also can connect via commandline, from another computer, so firwall looks open to me

Comment: Is the LAN ip-address of the Netgear in the same range as your TFTP server? Most Netgear equipment defaults to 192.168.1.0/255. And many devices (not just Netgear) restrict TFTP (because it is so insecure) to only work in the same subnet as the device. So you can't use TFTP accross a router-hop on such devices.

Comment: I have subnetmask 192.168.0.0/24 all are in same subnet , there are only switches in between no routers

Comment: Hi, yes Netgear is in the same LAN. I did set IP manually to 
192.168.0.0/24 for all devices.
that is still strange to me
Thanks

Comment: What TFTP server are you using? What command line client is the one that works? a Wireshark traffic capture will show you what's really going on at packet level